# Stylesheets not loading on Woocommerce archive and single product pages leaving them unformatted

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've encountered an interesting problem on one of my client's Woocommerce archive and single product pages.

For some reason, no stylesheet is loading at all on these pages and they are completely unformatted. Oddly enough, the stylesheets seem to be loading on the cart and checkout page just fine. This is a pretty basic store, all I really need is the default Woocommerce stylesheets to load for now.

Archive:
http://lifeserveltd.com/online/shop/

Single Product Example:
http://lifeserveltd.com/online/product/1-life-story/

From my research, I came across two possible answers online and implemented them both with no luck yet.

The first possible fix I came across suggested putting `<?php body_class(); ?>` inside the `<body>` tag like this in header.php:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

I can confirm that this is done.

The second solution involves editing the woocommerce.php file by  wrapping the

`<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>` in a `<div class="woocommerce"></div>`

Unfortunately, the people in the articles didn't share the exact syntax they used so I tried a couple different ways of "wrapping". Here is what I tried. (I'm new to wordpress development so don't laugh too hard):

```
<div class="woocommerce"><?php woocommerce_content(); ?></div>


<div class="woocommerce" <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>></div>


<div class="woocommerce"><?php woocommerce_content(); ?> PAGE CONTENT </div>
```

1) Am I doing this right?

2) If so, what else could cause the stylesheets not to load?

I will post the articles referencing solutions in the comments because I have reached my link limit.

Thanks in advance for anyone who puts time into helping me with a solution. I deeply appreciate your time and effort and will find a way to pay it forward somehow.

Comment: Body tag fix:
http://idnetter.com/solved-woocommerce-css-style-not-working/

div wrapper fix:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/2739

Another article referencing both solutions:
https://stanhub.com/how-to-fix-default-woocommerce-css-not-working-properly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the header of the page, in your woocommerce.php are you making sure to call `get_header();` at the top? Here are some links for reference:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Comment: Well... that did the trick. Can't believe I missed that. I just went straight into the rabbit hole and didn't check to see if I all of the pieces were there in the first place. Thank you so much. 

I upvoted your response but it won't show up because my account is too new.